# View PDF in browser without Download (Something like gmail attachment)

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, pdf-viewer, pdfviewer

We are using php to generate PDF on server. 
Can you please help me to understand, how to give facility to user to view PDF online (something like feature of Gmail) ?

Any reference document will be of great help.

[image]

In this figure, if I click on PDF icon / anywhere outside two buttons to download / recycle ; I can view pdf with lighbox effect in the background. 
If I click on Download , pdf get's downloaded on the client machine.

Is there any way to achieve similar effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383644/html-pdf-viewer)